# How to compile and run a C/C++ program on the Android system (like MinGW on the Windows)?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-emulator

I want to compile and run the C/C++ program on the Android phone program (like G1).

For example, I write a "Hello World.c" program, then compile and run it on my Android phone system.

I have never used MinGW to run my code on my Windows system, so I also want to do it on the Android phone system.

Answer (score 6):

At the time of the other answers, it may have been true that there were no development options. However, that area is changing quickly. There are several projects now where you can develop in some languages. Not all utilities support all ansi standards of the languages yet. As an example the project C4droid seems to aim to give full ansi C/C++.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en

Comment: c4droid is surprisingly powerful. I took the NDK graphics demo code (expecting it to choke), it compiled out of the box, graphics and all.  

Wish the editor/IDE was better though. Ideally I could just use vim as a front end (I know I could use the vim app, but task switching to compile is a pita).

Comment: c4droid is **paid** and i think it's too much to **pay to the dev for free and open-source gcc**. you can find better and free alternatives in Google Play

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend **CppDroid** - new free C/C++ IDE and compiler on Android. It has a lot of included C/C++ examples and tutorials. YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T5qNP6xJ6Y#t=14  Blog: http://cppdroid.blogspot.com, Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid

Answer (score 1):

The only way of using C/C++ in Android is to use the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

today i just tried a new thing
it is super-hacky but works great after you set it up.
first root your phone(use something easy like z4root).
and follow the instructions here:
http://www.gphone.org.hk/cgi-bin/ch/threaded_show.cgi?tid=69&pid=222&h=1

If it is hard for you to use adb, then your just like me.use QuickSSHd.
**DO NET SET THE SAME PASSWORD FOR QuickSSHd and OpenSSH.it won't make any changes in the process, but helps you not to get confused.**
After you done everything,
**be sure that the last few statements have worked correctly./this one may hurt**

After you **make sure than OpenSSH is installed *Correctly***.
Close QuickSSHd and ssh into your Debian.

then you can
apt-get install g++

Update to squeeze after you make sure it works.

And have fun.

Hint: **never close the shell in the process == use usb network instead of wifi if possible**

Any questions, I'm ready.

Comment: Compile is really faster than my desktop debian.
Using galaxy tab.

Comment: you can probably (compile and) install `screen` or `tmux` on your device in order to avoid requiring permanent connection during

Comment: also, the link you gave is dead, and thus renders this answer mostly useless :/

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Everything in this answer is dead, QuickSSHd, z4root, the versions that used to work with those models. new phones can run chroot easily with just a few lines of java code. try that with debootstrap. or use another phone/OS that have sysv style init script hooks and chroot shipped by default(e.g. cyanogenmod). again with debootstrap. you can also try 'airlied's work with adreno GPU drivers and his fedora distribution.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler screen didn't work on those devices, actually. no pty/pts

Comment: dark times... fortunately things have improved a bit by now

Answer (score 0):

You can use clang from within the terminal emulator Termux. It's all free!
I installed Termux through the Play Store, then once I got to the terminal, i used:

```
pkg install clang

clang++ hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux

If you are unfamiliar with using a terminal emulator, check this page:
https://www.learntermux.tech/2020/01/basic-commands-in-termux.html